# Прервать выполнение программы в консоли

Tags: c#

Уважаемые программисты, подскажите, каким образом можно прервать консольную программу на C# ?

Comment: В какой момент?

Comment: Во время выполнения, разумеется. например, если не удовлетворяется какое-либо условие. оператор break; не предлагать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый правильный способ прервать выполенение кода на каком-либо его учатске - это оператор `return`. В Вашем случае его просто необходимо вставить в нужное место в методе `main`.

Если по каким-либо причинам он Вам не подходит, то есть ещё несколько способов:

1. `System.Environment.Exit()` - завершение текущего процесса.
2. `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()` - заврешение текущего потока исключением `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException`.

Первый из предложенных вариантов Вам вполне подойдёт, но подумайте ещё раз о структуре программы.

Answer (score 1):

Нажмите Ctrl+C во время выполнения. Пример

```
using System;

class Hello { 
    static void Main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("hello, world");

    }
}
```

Компилируете

> `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" hello.cs`

Выполняете

> `hello.exe`

И прерываете.

Answer (score 0):

1. `return  #код_возврата;` 
   `(если выход должен производится из главной "`main()`" функции)
2. `Environment.Exit(#код_возврата );`